# Как сделать сайт на Django динамическим?

Tags: python, json, django

Сайт показывает погоду города, которого человек ищет в строке. Данные берутся из json. Но после поиска сайт перезагружается и появляются данные о погоде. Но можно ли сделать так, чтобы данные появлялись без перезагрузки? Спасибо, заранее.

Comment: Написать javascript, который будет отправлять ajax-запрос на сервер и по получении ответа обновлять содержимое страницы. Django здесь в общем-то ни при чём

Comment: Просто сайт работает на Джанго, это имелось в виду.

Comment: @AmirhanAmirov Django, как и любой другой web-фреймворк, умеет обрабатывать ajax-запросы.